# can websites reach cookies which are left from other websites?

Tags: cookies

Can websites reach and use cookies which are left from other websites? And are there coookie like technologies which we cannot simply delete from our browsers settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View cookies of others? Yes you can. Depending on cookie settings.
Permanent cookies? No you can not. Browser will not allow for such cheap tricks.

Answer (score 3):

No, the   [same origin policy forbids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)   that